# does negative index necessarily mean undefined behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
int main(){
    vector<vector<int>> a;
    a.resize(2,vector<int>(2));
    int arr[2][2];
    cout<<&arr[1][1]<<endl;
    cout<<&arr[2][-1]<<endl;
    cout<<&a[1][1]<<endl;
    cout<<&a[2][-1];

}
```

The output to this program shows that `arr[2][-1]` and `arr[1][1]` both correspond to the same address. It is not true for the vector though. I want to ask is using negative index undefined behavior in case of an array.
Because if it's not, I can use this property keeping in mind that I don't cross the lower bound.

Comment: Negative indexes are ok for pointers that are properly initialized. Ex: `int ar[10]; int *p = &ar[5]; cout << p[-2];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Undefined Behavior in two places.

When you reference `a[2]`, this is UB because `a` only has two elements, and `a[2]` is past the end. (Don't think of `a` as a 2D vector; think of it as a vector of vectors.)

Even if you try to access `a[1][-1]`, this is also UB because indexing is unsigned, the -1 will be converted to a really big positive number, and the subsequent access will be out of bounds.

Also, the memory for `arr` is contiguous, but for `a` it is not (since it comes from three separate memory allocation calls).

Comment: note that "indexing is unsigned" only applies to the `vector` where we call `operator[](size_t)`; this is not the case for built-in arrays where `x[y]` is defined as being `*(x+y)` which is pointer arithmetic between pointer and integer

Answer (score 2):

It's technically undefined behavior, but it will probably work as long as you don't cross the lower bound because 2d arrays are stored in contiguous memory.

Comment: Each vector is contiguous by itself, here you have a vector of vectors.
The inner vectors are not contagious in the memory, because each of those allocate in a different address in the heap.

Comment: I know vectors aren't contiguous and that it wouldn't work with vectors. That's why I said arrays.

Comment: The question seems to have been mainly about arrays

Comment: still unsigned though.

Comment: Do you have a source for saying it's unsigned for arrays? It's definitely *acting* as if it's signed (for arrays only).

Comment: I was mistaken, you are right. Array indices work with pointer arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

The argument for the `vector::operator[]` is from the type `vector::size_type`, which is an unsigned type. 
When you use `-1` it implicitly cast it to be unsigned, which is the biggest value possible of the type, definitely out_of_range in your case.
`vector::operator[]` does not check if the index is out of bound. If you would use the `vector::at` function it will also throw an `out_of_bound` exception.